# Filter data to get last month for each month in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
x <- data.frame("date" = c("2018-09-12","2018-09-11", "2018-06-23","2018-06-12","2018-06-10","2019-09-12","2019-09-23"), value1 = c(22,45,23,12,11,2,23))
> x    
    date        value1
1 2018-09-12     22
2 2018-09-11     45
3 2018-06-23     23
4 2018-06-12     12
5 2018-06-10     11
6 2019-09-12      2
7 2019-09-23     23
```

I need to sort on date column and then get only the last value of month in a particular month, like this:

```
month      value1  
2018-09-12  22     
2018-06-23  23     
2019-09-23  23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to year month as grouping column and slice

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
   mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
   arrange(date) %>%
   group_by(yearmon = as.yearmon(date)) %>% 
   slice(n()) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-yearmon)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  date       value1
#  <date>      <dbl>
#1 2018-06-23     23
#2 2018-09-12     22
#3 2019-09-23     23
```

---

Or create the 'yearmon' column with `format` from `base R`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
   mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
   arrange(date) %>%
   group_by(yearmon = format(date, '%Y-%m')) %>% 
   slice(n()) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-yearmon)
```